# Placing images programatically on page ASP.net Web application c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, web, controls

How can I move an image control programatically ? in a asp.net web application on that page, I wish to create 3 images programatically and place them with some distance between them;

```
int punctX = 50;
            int punctY=50;

            for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                image.ID = "culoare" + y.ToString();
```

-- how to place image on page?
}

Comment: Where are the images stored, in the DB?

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you can use some kind of a place holder to add your images into. Here in this example I am using a asp.net panel control. In the code behind you can set the style property with the corresponding attributes.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverFlow_2._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlImages" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Provided you have images like this

[image]

You can do something like this (not may be the cleanest code; but you get the idea)

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace StackOverFlow_2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                double punctX = 10;
                double punctY = 10;

                double spacing = 5;

                pnlImages.Style["position"] = "relative";

                for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                    image.ID = "culoare" + y.ToString();
                    image.Style["position"] = "absolute";
                    image.Style["left"] = punctX.ToString() + "px";
                    image.Style["top"] = punctY.ToString() + "px";
                    image.Width = 100;
                    image.Height = 60;
                    image.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + image.ID.ToString() + ".jpg";

                    pnlImages.Controls.Add(image);                    

                    punctX += image.Width.Value + spacing;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rendered output looks like this (your images are placed 5px apart)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add them to your page control collection  like this

```
page.Controls.Add(yourImage)
```

Comment: and then? how do I place them at given X and Y location?

Comment: Why do you want to give them X,Y ?

Comment: because I want them to be at desired location, and with some space between them

Comment: is that possible? to do programatically?

Comment: My advise would be for you to Add images in a Panel and give margins via CssClass property

Comment: what is the difference between margin-left and left?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //The image data is from database.
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    img.ID = row["id"].ToString();
    img.AlternateText = row["id"].ToString();
    img.ImageUrl = "~/myimage.png";
    img.Style["position"] = "relative";              //here must be "relative"
    img.Style["left"] = row["posX"].ToString() + "px";
    img.Style["top"] = row["posY"].ToString() + "px";
```