# get images from folder and set to datatype

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am Trying to get images from a folder and add them to type image type but found this error..
 Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image'

```
      Image image;
      string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Hari\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite26\img\");
      int numFiles = fileEntries.Length;
      for (int picCount = 0; picCount < numFiles; picCount++)
      {
          image = fileEntries[picCount];
      }
```

Comment: When talking about [tag:asp.net] do not use the tag [tag:asp] as it is a synonym for [tag:asp-classic] which is very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your for loop to this:

```
for (int picCount = 0; picCount < numFiles; picCount++)
{
    image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    // set other image properties
    // also i assume that you web root is 'C:\Users\Hari\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite26'
    image.ImageUrl = "/img/" + Path.GetFileName(fileEntries[picCount]);
}
```

anyway purpose of your task is not well understood.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443697/placing-images-programatically-on-page-asp-net-web-application-c-sharp) post about creating images programmaticaly and adding them to resulting page.

Comment: Got this error                                                  Error 1 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromFile'